# How do I create a non-standard type with SOAPpy?

Tags: python, web-services, soap

I am calling [a WSDL web service](http://www.pingdom.com/services/api-documentation/) from Python using [SOAPpy](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/). The call I need to make is to the method [Auth_login](http://www.pingdom.com/services/api-documentation/operation_login). This has 2 arguments - the first, a string being the API key; the second, a [custom type containing username and password](http://www.pingdom.com/services/api-documentation/class_CredentialsData). The custom type is called Auth_credentialsData which contains 2 values as stings - one for the username and one for the password. How can I create this custom type using SOAPpy? I tried passing a list and a dictionary, none of which work.

Code so far:

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL

wsdlUrl = 'https://ws.pingdom.com/soap/PingdomAPI.wsdl'
client = WSDL.Proxy(wsdlUrl)
```

Tried both:

```
credentials = ['email@example.com', 'password']
client.Auth_login('key', credentials)
```

and

```
credentials = {'username': 'email@example.com', 'password': 'passsword'}
client.Auth_login('key', credentials)
```

both of which give an authentication failed error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better method is to use the ZSI soap module which allows you to take a WDSL file and turn it into classes and methods that you can then use to call it. The online documentation is  [on their website](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html#SECTION0012300000000000000000) but the latest documentation is more easily found in the source package. If you install in Debian/Ubuntu (package name python-zsi) the documentation is in /usr/share/doc/python-zsi in a pair of PDFs you can find in there.